# display messages to the client using JMS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, queue, jms

is there any way to display messages on the JMS Queue to the client JSP ?

so if any  message inserted into the Queue (MessageDrivenBean) , it will shows to the client (browser) ,,

thank you ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u cannot sent the message to a jsp directly. means u will have no idea when the message will come right so it is async way of communication. In a jsp u can have a ajax component wherein we can poll to the backend system and get populate the messages recieved in a given point of time in intervals.

Answer (score 1):

You Could create a servlet or JSP that responds to some user action like a button click or page refresh and calls the bean to see if there are any in the Queue. You could also call a method in the bean from the servlet that returns the number in queue, etc.

Comment: thank you , but the problem how long will be the Message in the Queue ? so when user offline ? how i can show the Message ? if i have huge number of the Messages in the Queue , i have to use while loop to get the Message for the user , so i think it's so costly ! :(